# Enumerate \item with a decimal value

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm using enumerate to create an outline that already exists.  (As in, I'm copying an existing list, and I get no say in the numbers that are already picked.)  My problem is that occasionally the outlines have a fractional value thrown in.  One of the sections proceeds like: 1, 2, 2.5, 3.

I tried using `\setcounter{enumi}{1.5}` before where 2.5 goes, but LaTeX didn't like that at all.  This works, but is a little clunky:

```
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi.5)}
\item This is item number 2.5.
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
```

Is there a better way to have a decimal value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo
 \item bar
 \item[(2.5)] foobar
 \item baz
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: *smack* Yup, that did it.  You can even format in there, so I could `\item[(2.5)]` like I need to.  And it doesn't increment the enumi counter, which is nice.